# I want to take the Fourier transform of Schrodinger equation of hydrogen atom.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the Schrodinger equation of hydrogen atom as 
$$ i\hbar \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} =  -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\varphi+V\varphi$$
where $\varphi$ is a function of $r, \theta, \phi,t$.
I want to take fourier transform of this equation in spherical polar coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour)! But where is the question mark in this question?

Comment: If question mark is necessary, you can read it as "how to take the fourier transform?" .

Comment: It would be wonderful if you can show your attempts at taking the fourier transform; or edit your equations to be expressed in $\LaTeX$ format, which is done by `$\hat H \varphi = $` ...

Comment: Do you want to transform the spatial variables?  If so, there is an issue regarding the transform of the product $V(r)\phi(r,\theta,\phi)$.